# How to print the string result in this code

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, printing, instance

I want the displayed result to be a string, not a memory address

```
 def display(self):
    selected_item = None
    if selected_item is None:
        print("Choose an option:")
        print(*enumerate(self.items), sep='\n')
        print("0. Back")
```

I expect the above code to print a string

Comment: What is the value of `self.items`? If it's a list of strings it will print something like `(0, 'abc')
(1, 'def')`. That's not a memory address, it's a tuple for each item.

Comment: hi,
value is list,
result this:

Choose an option:
(0, <__main__.MenuItem object at 0x0000020CFA538B10>)
(1, <__main__.MenuItem object at 0x0000020CFA538B50>)
(2, <__main__.MenuItem object at 0x0000020CFA538B90>)
(3, <__main__.MenuItem object at 0x0000020CFA538BD0>)
0. Back

Answer (score 1):

The elements of `self.items` are instances of the `MenuItem` class, not strings. When you print a tuple, it prints the `repr()` of each element; unless you define a `__repr__()` method in the class, the repr shows the memory address.

You'll need to format the output to get it converted to a string (I'm assuming it has a `__str__()` method.

```
def display(self):
    selected_item = None
    if selected_item is None:
        print("Choose an option:")
        print(*(f"{i}. {item}" for i, item in enumerate(items, 1)), sep='\n')
        print("0. Back")
```

Comment: I should not use loop in this question

Comment: I  replaced the loop with a generator. You could also use `map()`